# Make ListView scroll vertical by MouseWheel

Tags: c#, listview

How can I make a WinForms ListView scroll vertical by MouseWheel?

I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK if the list scrolls only when it has focus?  If so, use the [`Control.MouseWheel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel(VS.85).aspx) event.

Do you want the list to scroll if it doesn't have focus?  Then you need to need to either implement a mouse hook, as described in the other article, or take a look at the [`Application.AddMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) method.  `Application.AddMessageFilter` gives you a managed version of a mouse hook.  You get to preview the messages as they come in.  I wrote something about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161280/parent-control-mouse-enter-leave-events-with-child-controls).

Comment: I just want to scroll it if it has focus

Comment: OK, then MouseWheel should work.  Override MouseWheel.  Figure out which way to scroll (down for positive delta, I think?), take the current selected index, add a known value to it, and call ListView.EnsureVisible(newIndex).

Comment: Err, when I say "known value", come up with a rule like "wheel down = 4 rows", and call EnsureVisible(listView.SelectedIndex + 4) on the new index, but don't forget to limit the bounds of the new index.

Comment: I'll have a try and post back later