# Catching User Input in C# COM Client

Tags: c#, c++, com, mfc

Using VS2003 (.Net 1.1) We have an MFC MDI application that spawns a C# window as a COM client.

We need to catch all user input within the application and we're currently using CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage() to catch the commands headed to the MFC windows but this obviously doesn't catch the messages headed to the C# window.

What is the best way of catching all user input within the C# client?

Comment: What interfaces are you using to host it?  It may support one of the standard OLE interfaces that will let you do this...

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the C# window?  If so, C# forms have a `WndProc` method that you can override and filter the messages there.

If this where a standard WinForms app, you could add a handler to `Application.AddMessageFilter` to create a message hook inside C#.  (See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161280/parent-control-mouse-enter-leave-events-with-child-controls).)  I'm not sure this would work given the form is inside an MFC app.

Comment: We do control the C# client.
It has a number of different controls in it so do I have to write a WndProc method for each control? Or do all the messages pass through a "global" one somewhere?
Also, I'd tried the AddMessageFilter route but sometimes the method was called but often it wasn't.  Why is this?

Comment: Ahh, I see that it's possible to catch all message with WndProc:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/devicevolumemonitor.aspx

Comment: After many attempts I couldn't get this to work. I wanted to capture the messages so that I could redirect the user to a login dialog but I ended up doing this in the MFC code and just disabled the C# window when logged out.