# HWnd Message Hook in WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

What is the WinForms equivalent to the following line of WPF code?

```
HwndSource.FromHwnd(_windowHandle).AddHook(HwndSourceHookHandler);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WinForms, you'd typically [override WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) in the control/Form in question.  Since every control is effectively a `HWND`, you don't need the `HwndSource` style of hooking.

---

If you want to setup a Hook in C#, you can follow the guidelines in [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804).

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your input.  I am looking to have a class, separate from the respective form, handle the registering of messages etc., where the constructor will take in an instance of the Window/Form, at which point I need to know how, using the window's/form's handle, to register the messages.  Apologies if my initial post was not clear.

Comment: @Chris: Are you after how to setup a Windows Hook, ie:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

Comment: Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx  for full details on Hooks

Comment: Reed - yes - specifically curious about how to setup a Windows Hook.

Comment: @Chris: Okay - that first link (edited my answer to include it) walks through how to do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your own process, you can use the [Application.AddMessageFilter method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) to listen to specific events before they are dispatched anywhere.  This doesn't work between processes.

I found this while searching for an answer to one of [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161280/parent-control-mouse-enter-leave-events-with-child-controls) about handling of mouse events between parent and child controls.