# MouseLeave Event With Two Panels

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 panels (`Panel1` and `Panel2`) with `Panel2` placed inside of `Panel1`

My code:

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
    MsgBox("Leave")
End Sub
```

The `MsgBox` pops-up when my mouse goes inside `Panel2`.

This is not logical, because my mouse is still contained in the area of ​​`Panel1`.

How can `Panel2` be considered the same area as `Panel1` for event purposes?

Comment: or this one for that matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161280/parent-control-mouse-enter-leave-events-with-child-controls
although, the code in an answer kinda' lacks the working part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following figure,

[image]

Assume that the above picture is representing a two concrete slabs(`Two panels`) placed one above another (light gray:`panel1`, dark gray: `panel2`).

You are the person(`Cursor`) asked to stand up on position 1 in light-gray slab, what you will do, 
 First you will enter into the light gray slab.[`panel1.mouseEnter event got fired` ] and finally you will reach the positon 1. similarly again you asked to stand up on the position 2 in dark gray slab,
what you will do this time, you will leave the light gray slab [`panel1.mouseLeave event got fired`] and then you will enter into the dark gray slab [`panel2.mouseEnter event got fired`]. 
 Did you notice.? you had left the light gray slab in order to enter into the dark gray one.

Similarly, Inside a `form`, especially on a stack of `controls`, One Control's `Mouse Enter` should be the previous control's `Mouse Leave`.

Comment: Not exactly true. You can (very fast, programmatically, using pen hovering above the screen with pen input) move the mouse *right into* the position two, so there won't be any events for the `panel1` at all.

Comment: @Gman you are right, it is a known issue.But OP's requirement is to know, `why Panel1's leave event called, still mouse is inside of it`. and by the way i thought that he needed a logical answer. :)