# Mouse leave on a panel with children

Tags: c#, panel

Good morning, 
I try to make a drop-down menu when I move the mouse over a part of my panel.
The problem is, to hide my panel when the mouse leaves the panel, I use mouseLeave() but if I go on a control that is in the panel, the mouseLeave method is also called.

I tried this:

```
        internal List<Object> exeptions = new List<object>();

        public UserControl_Projet_Vue()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach(var outil in panel_outils.Controls)
            {
                exeptions.Add(outil);
            }
            exeptions.Add(panel_outils);
        }
```

But I don't know afterwards how to know if the smile went on an "exception" or not ;(

Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, not that simple: [Parent Control Mouse Enter/Leave Events With Child Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161280/parent-control-mouse-enter-leave-events-with-child-controls)